# I want to construct a GraphML File by generating the nodes and edges

Tags: python, xml, graphml

i need to create a file with .graphML extension, The file will have a header and footer so the execution is like

output file contains:

**header**

**generated nodes list**

**generated edge list**

**footer**

the header and footer are available in text file or it can also be hardcoded the code needs to generate the nodes and edges getting input from the user recursively

any suggestions?

Comment: What part of this are you having difficulty with? We don't know what the input is, or what the algorithm looks like, so it's unlikely we can help.

Comment: i am new to python, so i have difficulty in generating the nodes and edges  https://github.com/MohanSha/Generate_GraphML-file/tree/master

Comment: @MichaelKay the repository has a pytho file named conc.py , i have managed to append the header and footer from the text files to create a new .graphml file. Now the nodes and edges needs to be generated and appended  inbetween the header and footer